# Relation between complex and real sphere

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I want to understand relation between complex and real spheres. 
How to show?

$S^1(\mathbb{C}) \approx \mathbb{R} \times S^1$
$S^3(\mathbb{C}) \approx \mathbb{R} \times S^3$

$\approx$ means homotopy equivalence.

Comment: What is your definition of $S^1(\mathbb{C})$ and $S^3(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: $S^n (\mathbb{C}) = \{ (z_0, z_1, \ldots , z_n) \in \mathbb{C}^{n+1} ; \ z_0^2 +\ldots +z_n^2=1 \} $

Comment: I guess he know the definition, but yours is wrong, $S^n(C)=\{z \in \mathbb{C}^{n+1}: \|z\|=1\}$, and yours is not even a norm.

Comment: I don't take this as set definied by norn. For  me $S^n(\mathbb{C})$ is aﬃne quadric ddeﬁned by the equation.

Comment: Well but that is really not an answer to the question anyway. Your sphere is not bounded is that on purpose ?

Comment: I don't know that.

Comment: Well take $S^2(\mathbb{C}$ with your definition and the points $(1,n,ni)$ this makes $1^2+n^2 -n^2 =1$ neverthe less what n is

Comment: Ok, you have right. This set may be not bounded. For me important case is for n=1,3.

Comment: Are you Piotrekkk ?